# In a longer time or For a longer time

Tags: prepositional-phrases

If I want to express "To spend more time travelling to the workplace." Which phrases below can I use here?

- To travel **in a longer time** to the workplace.
- To travel **for a longer time** to the workplace.

Can you please explain me which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

"for a longer time" is correct; "in a longer time" is not.

The reason is because what you are describing is the *duration* of the travel to the workplace.  "For _____" is generally how durations of time are described.  For example: "I traveled for an hour to work." or "The United States has been a country for centuries."

The same applies if the duration is instead a comparison between lengths of time: "She traveled for a longer time than I did." or "England has been a country for a longer time than the United States."